# How can I block referral traffic from AND to a specific domain?

Tags: .htaccess, referer

I need to block incoming traffic from Google using htaccess. The installation is running several domains, but I only need to block the traffic for one specific domain.

I've tried the following, but this always blocks all requests.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://(www\.)?google\.(com|de|fr|ch)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.org [NC]
RewriteRule .* – [F]
```

Comment: "but this always blocks all requests." - Well, it will only block all requests for the requested hostname that matches the stated regex (ie. `www.example.org` or `example.org`) - which would seem to be what you require? Are you suggesting that it's blocking requests for all domains? (That's not possible with the rule as posted.) What other directives do you have?

Comment: I need it to only block requests from Google. It currently blocks everything, including requests with no referrer.

Comment: Again, that's not possible with the rule you've posted. It specifically checks that the `Referer` request header _is_ "google".

Comment: Yes: if the referrer is Google and the host is example.org, then requests should be blocked with a 403 error.

Comment: The rule you've posted should already do as you require. If other requests (from different referrers) are also being blocked then _something else_ would seem to be doing that. (Make sure you've your browser and any intermediary caches.)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I get that it *should*, but it doesn't. I completely reset my browsers before and after trying, and with the code above amended for the domain of my website, all requests are blocked, even those with no referrer.

Comment: How are you testing this? Change the response to something other than a 403 to make sure it really is this rule that is being triggered. Change the regex in the first condition to something that would never match - is the rule still triggered? Like I say, it is **impossible** for that rule to be triggered if the `Referer` header really is empty.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. I'd introduced a syntax error in the version on the server, which wasn't evident in the snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

The code in my initial question is correct. I'd introduced a spelling error when modifying it for my specific server.